# How to use existing namespace with variable object name in mel expression?

Tags: mel

I have an existing namespace called "Target" that I want to hardcode in my script.
What is the proper syntax to combine the "Target:" namespace with the $joints[$1] variable below? The way it is now definitely doesn't work.

connectAttr -f ("Target:" + $joints[$i] + ".worldMatrix[0]") ($nodeName + ".target[0].targetMatrix");

Thank you for any guidance!